# Finding and replacing pattern in memory

Tags: c++, memory

I've been struggling with this for the better part of a day, rewriting every which way and referencing documentation and even other people's code, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to get my code to work.

A thread in my process is attempting to search the memory of another thread. I'm looking to fix something in a specific module, but I'm furthermore not sure how to or if it's worth narrowing down my search, so right now it's just searching the entire process--and possibly itself? Who knows?

Whenever I latch on a debugger, I can **find** this set of bytes just fine (equivalent to `mov rsi, rax; test dil, 1; jz short loc_...`), but for the life of me I can't at all seem to find it.

I found that I did **rarely** find it, which definitely means that for some reason my search appears to be accessing... well, irrelevant things, and probably finding this purely by chance. I've absorbed so many names and concepts in a single day I think it just isn't sitting right in my head. What's going wrong here?

Addon.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Addon.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int pattern[] = { 0x48, 0x8B, 0xF0, 0x40, 0xF6, 0xC7, 0x01, 0x74, 0x3E };
int replace[] = { 0x48, 0x8B, 0xF0, 0x40, 0xF6, 0xC7, 0x00, 0x75, 0x3E };

DWORD WINAPI background(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    HANDLE h = GetCurrentProcess();

    while (true) //for now
    {
        MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
        unsigned char* p = NULL;

        for (p = NULL; VirtualQueryEx(h, p, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)) == sizeof(mbi); p += mbi.RegionSize)
        {
            std::vector<char> buffer;
            if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Type == MEM_MAPPED || mbi.Type == MEM_PRIVATE)
            {
                SIZE_T bytes_read;
                buffer.resize(mbi.RegionSize);
                ReadProcessMemory(h, p, &buffer[0], mbi.RegionSize, &bytes_read);
                buffer.resize(bytes_read);
            }

            std::vector<char> new_tail(buffer.end() - 9, buffer.end());
            for (char t : old_tail)
                buffer.push_back(t);
            old_tail = new_tail;

            if (std::search(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), std::begin(pattern), std::end(pattern) != buffer.end())
            {
                MessageBoxA(NULL, "Found", "Found", NULL);
            }
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Added other files on request.

Addon.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"

#ifdef ADDON_EXPORTS
#define ADDON_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ADDON_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DWORD WINAPI background(LPVOID lpParam);
```

dllmain.cpp

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>

#include "Addon.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            DWORD thread;
            CreateThread(NULL, 0, background, 0, 0, &thread);

            if (thread == NULL)
            {
                MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to start crash fix", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
            }
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide [mcve]

Comment: What happens if half the pattern is in one chunk and half in the next?

Comment: I can't hand out the binary. How can I improve the question? Are you referring to simply giving out the header file and the DllMain? Since this function runs just fine. It's just either not targeting the right place or not searching correctly. I've added them for completion sake.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Oh... Yes, I forgot that in the old code I was searching one megabyte at the time, making this extremely unlikely. Exactly how large is RegionSize?

Comment: Why would the size of the non-overlapping blocks you're checking have anything to do with the pattern starting a few bytes before the end of one block and running into the next one? For an effective search you must take that possibility into account. It's your code, if you want to know the contents of a variable like RegionSize, print it out or look in the debugger.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I've addressed your concern.

Comment: For the record you don't have to use a `std::vector` to use `std::search` because pointers are iterators and you can use `std::begin(pattern), std::end(pattern)` on native arrays to obtain beginning and end iterators.

Comment: _... for the better part of a day_ 

Sometimes the answer stares you right in the  good eye.

Comment: @Galik Thank you for the clarification. Though I'll stress that for the record, the problem was not solved by either using std::search or accounting for the 8-byte sequence being smack in the middle between two pages every time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the definition of `pattern` (and `replace`). It was defined as int, whereas it should be char. As Ted Lyngmo said, 'sometimes the answer stares you right in the good eye.'

Comment: Don't worry, it won't be the last time... It happens to us all (hopefully less frequently as you develop your skills).